# AC600 wifi 5ghz dongle or Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, 20.04, realtek

I bought a 5ghz wifi dongle called simply `AC600` and plugged in Ubuntu 20.04, `5.10.0-051000rc6-lowlatency` and the wifi wont work. Also tested on `5.8` kernel from ubuntu where it appears as `Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. DISK`

```
lz@xps13:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 067: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0c45:672a Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 003 Device 063: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:533c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The device is `Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC`

`dmesg` output of when I plug it:

```
[158313.992010] usb 3-8: new high-speed USB device number 64 using xhci_hcd
[158314.388264] usb 3-8: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=1a2b, bcdDevice= 2.00
[158314.388266] usb 3-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[158314.388267] usb 3-8: Product: DISK
[158314.388268] usb 3-8: Manufacturer: Realtek
[158314.389332] usb-storage 3-8:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[158314.389515] scsi host0: usb-storage 3-8:1.0
```

Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That's a BlueShadow AC600, which uses an RTL8812AU. There's a pretty decent driver available for this from the `aircrack-ng` team [available on GitHub](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au), and it's not too difficult to get it going.

From a terminal, if you don't already have `dkms` on your machine:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms
```

Now we can clone the `5.6.4.2` branch, which is one of the more stable versions:

```
git clone -b v5.6.4.2 https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

From here the driver will install and your WiFi dongle should be picked up.

Comment: Do you know why this driver is not included in the linux kernel?

Comment: Nope. It would be nice to see more support for various hardware, particularly the (relatively) simple USB devices that "just work" with Windows and MacOS, but I can understand the complexity in sourcing drivers for every device under the sun.

Comment: The above doesn't seem to work any more, there is no dkms-install.sh file. The instructions in the readme offer a way to install it, but that didn't work for me either (Manjaro, not Ubuntu, so it may work on other distros)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same adapter. These commands fix the problem:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
cd rtl8821CU
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 8821cu
```

Comment: Installing things from random repos, especially kernel modules, and especially networking ones, is really dangerous. Only do it if you do not care about safety, but this is very dangerous

Comment: but I couldn't find any other working repositories. Would you please provide some advice, since I am new to Linux.

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't find either. I think it's going to take some time until this lands on the kernel I guess (that is, it's reviewed properly and integrated so it just works). It looks like this is your only option for now, but remember that anyone could have altered the code and inserted malicious stuff, and with kernel drivers it's worse since they can do anything to your computer. I just used a 2.4ghz instead of this one, even if it's slower.

Comment: I was unable to complete the installation because the bc package was missing, evidently not installed with build-essential.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Manjaro (using pamac instead of apt). Yes, it is "dangerous", but the source is open, I plan on looking through it later for bad stuff :-)

Answer (score 0):

This repository worked for me: https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU

But after installed, I needed to install **usb_switchmode** and run the following command:

`sudo usb_modeswitch -KW -v 0bda -p 1a2b`

Where **0bda:1a2b** is the device id in lsusb:

- Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
- Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
- Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:57cc Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HD WebCam
- Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:301d Dell Computer Corp. Dell Universal Receiver
- Bus 001 Device 003: ID 258a:002a SINO WEALTH Gaming KB
- **Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. DISK**
- Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

After command was executed my dongle show as:

Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC