# WI-FI adapter is not detected after reboot unless it is replugged-in

Tags: wireless, 20.04, usb, desktop-environments

I am USING Ubuntu 20.04 Fresh install and the only significant change I have made (except installing the drivers for the said adapter) is to disable "Wake on X" settings on BIOS since it caused the PC to reboot instead of shutting down. But even without this, 9 out of 10 cases, I do not see the wireless icon when I turn on the PC unless I take it out and plug it back in.
Is there a solution to this, where I can keep it plugged in at the back of the case and not bother at all?

Here is the Network manager log:

```
Mär 05 15:48:49 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955729.4703] agent-manager: agent[1a2f8924292a42c2,:1.80/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Mär 05 15:49:34 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955774.7539] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Mär 05 15:49:34 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955774.7546] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Mär 05 15:49:34 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955774.7605] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Mär 05 15:49:34 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955774.7761] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.2/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill>
Mär 05 15:49:34 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955774.7834] device (wlan0): interface index 3 renamed iface from 'wlan0' to 'wlx1cbfce65cf9d'
Mär 05 15:49:34 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955774.7896] device (wlx1cbfce65cf9d): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mär 05 15:49:35 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955775.4636] manager: (D4:0B:1A:E6:22:9C): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Mär 05 15:49:35 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955775.4642] device (D4:0B:1A:E6:22:9C): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mär 05 15:49:35 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955775.4679] device (D4:0B:1A:E6:22:9C): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mär 05 15:49:35 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955775.5155] sup-iface[0x5638a019a110,wlx1cbfce65cf9d]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Mär 05 15:49:35 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955775.5159] device (wlx1cbfce65cf9d): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Mär 05 15:49:35 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955775.5160] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlx1cbfce65cf9d created
Mär 05 15:49:35 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955775.5162] manager: (p2p-dev-wlx1cbfce65cf9d): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
Mär 05 15:49:35 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955775.5165] device (p2p-dev-wlx1cbfce65cf9d): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'externa>
Mär 05 15:49:35 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955775.5169] device (p2p-dev-wlx1cbfce65cf9d): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed>
Mär 05 15:49:35 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955775.5171] device (wlx1cbfce65cf9d): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: >
Mär 05 15:49:35 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <warn>  [1614955775.5234] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
Mär 05 15:49:39 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955779.4255] policy: auto-activating connection 'WLAN-07B646' (e1122307-80a2-41a8-b243-3cbd6bcbadab)
Mär 05 15:49:39 ifrat-ThinkCentre-M83 NetworkManager[603]: <info>  [1614955779.4263] device (wlx1cbfce65cf9d): Activation: starting connection 'WLAN-07B646' (e1122307-80a2-41a8-b243-3cbd6bcbadab)
```

In case it is relevant, these are the commands I have executed through terminal to get the dongle to be recognized by Ubuntu in the first place:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
cd rtl8821CU
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 8821cu
```

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: I posted the log to the main post, does it reveal any clues?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you restart Network Manager after a reboot, will the wireless device be picked up? I wonder if this has something to do with a supplicant function ... 

Comment: Similar to this question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083505/ubuntu-18-04-touchpad-not-fully-working-after-wake-from-suspend) you can create such a script for the module `iwlwifi`. I can't test it, but it might work.

Comment: Did you have a chance of testing any of what was posted?

Comment: Hello everyone, I thank everyone for their suggestions, I have been away from home for a few days, that's why I couldn't test them yet. I will award the good answers with the bounty reward anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you post additional information, namely:

1. Brand/model of your system. I guess it is a [ThinkCentre M83](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops/thinkcentre/m-series-sff/m83-sff/), but just in case.
2. Brand/model of your WiFi adapter. I will assume it is a USB adapter.
3. Where are you connecting the adapter? (front, back, hub, etc.)
4. The output of the *diagnostic commands* below (they are long, perhaps you can post short outputs here, and longer outputs in one or two zip files linked here), under two circumstances:

   4.1. WiFi not working (some commands would be meaningless).

   4.2. WiFi working.

*Possible causes of / workarounds/solutions to* your problem are as below.
Further action depends on your feedback.

---

**Diagnostic commands**

```
$ lsusb
$ udevadm info /dev/bus/usb/{BUS_NUMBER}/{DEVICE_NUMBER}
$ ifconfig
$ udevadm info /sys/class/net/{name of interface}
$ ip link
$ iw list
$ rfkill list
$ ifconfig
$ iwconfig
$ sudo systemctl status network-manager.service 
$ ls -1 /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants
$ lshw -C network
```

You may need to `sudo apt-get install` some packages ([`udev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271878/is-it-possible-to-get-the-devtype-of-a-usb-wifi-device), `iw`, `rfkill`).

---

**Possible causes of / workarounds/solutions to your problem**

1. The port you are connecting to. Try a different port.
2. Automatically restart the network (service, adapter, etc.) if needed.
   That is, right after boot, or from cron every few minutes, e.g.

   2.1. To work with the adapter you could use this script.

   ```
   if ! ping -I wlan0 -c 1 -Q 1 google.com ; then
       ifconfig wlan0 down
       sleep 5
       ifconfig wlan0 up
   fi
   sleep 5
   ```

   Replace `wlan0` with your interface name.

   2.2. To work with the service you could use this script.

   ```
   if ifconfig eth0 | grep -q "inet "; then
       # echo "all ok!"
   else
       systemctl restart network-manager.service 
   fi
   sleep 5
   ```

   2.3. To work with the driver you could use this script.

   ```
   modprobe -r <driver name>
   modprobe <driver name>
   ```

   Get the name with

   ```
   $ lspci -nnk | grep -i -A 4 network
   ```

   You can check further info with

   ```
   $ lsmod | grep <driver>
   $ modinfo <driver>
   ```

   Try if any/all of the three work to restore network when it is not working. If so, we could add them for automatic execution.

Depending on what you post, I could work alternative approaches.

---

**Related**

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/823908/226614

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, I collected the logs for the commands under both circumstances (when adapter is not working, also after it is re-plugged and working).

Regarding your questions:
1. It is ThinkCentre M83 as you noticed
2. It was an amazon brand which said (BT+AC600), it looks very much like this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301416/ac600-wifi-5ghz-dongle-or-realtek-semiconductor-corp-802-11ac-nic-on-ubuntu
The drivers that got it recognized by Ubuntu is on the main post.
3. All hubs, back or front behave the same
4. https://easyupload.io/m/fyz2h5

Answer (score 1):

#### Information

It is detected but renamed:

```
device (wlan0): interface index 3 renamed iface from 'wlan0' to 'wlx1cbfce65cf9d'
```

For the reasons and consequences of this behavior, please read [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/).

#### Solution

**Edit** `/etc/default/grub` like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

**Then**, add the option `net.ifnames=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` like so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash net.ifnames=0"
```

**Then**, save and close the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> then prss <kbd>y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**After that**, update GRUB like so:

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Finally**, reboot your system.